# first homolgy group of a disk with $n$ holes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $D^2$ be a 2-dim disk with $n$ holes, i.e $D^2\setminus(S^0 * D^2)^n$. Then is it true that the first homology group of this space is $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: What does $S^0*D^2$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is true, the fundamental group of this space is the free group generated by $n$ elements since it retracts to the bouquet of n circles, so its first homology which is the abelianization of its fundamental group is $Z^n$.